# How to model hidden layer with two emanating output to another two hidden layers?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, keras-layer

How do I model a hidden layer in Keras to output two outputs to be connected to two different hidden layers?

```
Input=x,
1st Hidden Layer(X),
2nd Hidden Layer(1st Hidden Layer),
3rd Hidden Layer (1st Hidden Layer)  # "also connected to 1st Hidden Layer instead of 2nd Hidden Layer"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the [Keras Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) for this purpose. For example you can write:

```py
inp = Input(shape=...)
h1 = Dense(...)(inp)
h2 = Dense(...)(h1)
h3 = Dense(...)(h1)   # it is connected to first hidden layer
```

I highly recommend you to read the linked guide.